# Activating Contact Form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I don't know any PHP at all so I researched a couple hours to try and get my contact form to actually save and send the inputs to my email. As of right now, I'm getting an error **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()**. Here is the contact form code and also PHP file code. They are located in the root directory, named index.html and contact.php. I'm using the template html5up.net/strata.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="form" class="contact-form">
   <div class="row uniform 50%">
       <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="cf_name" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
       <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="email" name="cf_email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
       <div class="12u$"><textarea name="cf_message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea></div>
   </div>
   <ul class="actions">
       <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special"/></li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'simonchangwong@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: where do you get that error? also, do you have a `contact_page.html` file as well?

Comment: Are you trying to use it in localhost?

Comment: I have run your code in my localhost and it not give me error like this.

Comment: I don't have contact_page.html, I'm using this template: https://html5up.net/strata

Comment: I'm pushing this code to my github.io portfolio. I get the error in the console but the page renders fine. When I hit "send message", it's a white page with "405 Not Allowed"